# Awk: parse node names out of "40*r13n15:40*r10n61:40*r11n18:40*r09n15"

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a linux script for selecting the node.

For example:

```
  4
  40*r13n15:40*r10n61:40*r11n18:40*r09n15
```

The correct result should be:

```
r13n15
r10n61
r11n18
r09n15
```

My linux script content is like:

```
hostNum=`bjobs -X -o "nexec_host" $1 | grep -v NEXEC`
hostSer=`bjobs -X -o "exec_host" $1 | grep -v EXEC`

echo $hostNum
echo $hostSer 

for i in `seq 1 $hostNum`
do
 echo $hostSer | awk -F ':' '{print '$i'}' | awk -F '*' '{print $2}'
done
```

But unlucky, I got nothing about node information.

I have tried:

```
echo $hostSer | awk -F ':' '{print "'$i'"}' | awk -F '*' '{print $2}'
```

and

```
echo $hostSer | awk -F ':' '{print '"$i"'}' | awk -F '*' '{print $2}'
```

But there are wrong. Who can give me a help?

Comment: i have tried How do I use shell variables in an awk script? (7 answers), but it is not ok again.echo $hostSer | awk -F ':'  -v a=$i '{print a}' | awk -F '*' '{print $2}'

Comment: The obvious and trivial bug is that you are missing the dollar sign before `{ print $a }` and similarly in `'{ print $'"$i"'}'` in your original code. But as all these answers suggest, you can easily avoid running Awk twice for this simple task.

Answer (score 3):

One more awk:

```
$ echo "$variable" | awk 'NR%2==0'  RS='[*:\n]'
r13n15
r10n61
r11n18
r09n15
```

By setting the record separtor(`RS`) to `*:\n` , the string is broken into individual tokens, after which you can just print every 2nd line(`NR%2==0`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple separators in awk. Please try below:

```
h='40*r13n15:40*r10n61:40*r11n18:40*r09n15'
echo "$h"| awk -F '[:*]' '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'
```

**edited to make it generic based on the comment from RavinderSingh13.